# Odoo 10 - Functions with onchange

Tags: python, odoo

I am coming to ask you for help to complete a function that allows you to select a school level according to an institution. I do not know what to upgrade to my last line of code. Currently, the chosen id is the very first of my recordings. Now, I want the id of the first element that is in comparison. Thank you

```
@api.onchange('school_name_id')
def _retrieve_grade_id(self):
    if self.school_name_id:
        records = self.env['horanet.school.grade'].search([])
        for rec in records:
            if rec.name:
                level = rec.name
                level = level.split()[-1]
                print level
                if level in self.school_name_id.name:
                    print "Il y a un mot trouvé"
                    self.school_level_id = self.env['horanet.school.grade'].search([], limit=1).id
```

Comment: Sorry impossible to undestand what you need exactly, the code will return the same result for a lot of records.

Comment: Can you explain why did you split the name, and can you give an example of a user sinario

Comment: Problem solved thanks to Axel Mendoza. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the last line. From this:

```
self.school_level_id = self.env['horanet.school.grade'].search([], limit=1).id
```

To this:

```
self.school_level_id = rec.id
break
```

break is added to prevent the first level found to be replaced by another result

Answer (score 0):

Hennion,

First think code for function based on 'id' not with 'name'. Because name may be multiple but id not. Also i think problem in your line 'if level in self.school_name_id.name:', it may be compare with equal(==) to sign.